# How do I do fill an EXISTING array in one line in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to fill my EXISTING (I know how to initialise it with these values) array with values using one line of code.

Here is what I am doing:

```
        floatbytearray[0] = 0x9A;
        floatbytearray[1] = 0x99;
        floatbytearray[2] = 0x19;
        floatbytearray[3] = 0x3e;
```

Comment: So you want to set multiple values at once?

Comment: Are you replacing all of the values in the array, or just a subset? I'm not sure there is a general way to do this; you could probably Array.Copy from another array, or just replace your array object entirely with a newly initialised one, depending on whether anything else holds a reference to the old array.

Comment: 1. Why do you want to set the values of an existing array rather than creating a new one? 2. Do you really need to do it in one line? Incidentally, you can do anything "in one line" by writing a method that does what you want done, and calling it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to utilize Lists instead of Arrays.

```
List<float> floats = new List<float>() {
  0x9A,
  0x99,
  ...
};
```

If you need an array as an output, you could simply do `floats.ToArray().`

Lists are much easier to handle than arrays, which is why I would recommend those.

Comment: Note that OP specifically states the "EXISTING" array is to be filled not a new one - so this does not answer the question.

Comment: Note that the values are bytes, not floats

Answer (score 0):

Lets say exist array of byte look like this  `byte[] array = new byte[] { 0x9A, 0x99 };`

then just use this to add new values into array

```
array = array.Concat(new byte[] { 0x19, 0x23}).ToArray();
```

> Note: add namespace `using System.Linq;`

Comment: This extends the array, the question asks about setting indices in place.

Comment: I dont think is possible to insert more than one element into two indexes at the same time.

Comment: Also note that [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return a new `IEnumerable<byte>` rather than modifying the existing `byte[]`, so this doesn't do what the OP wanted.